# Beginner C++: Tic Tac Toe

Tags: c++

I am taking my first coding class this year in school (High school/C++), and this is my first real attempt at coding anything other than book exercises.

I just wanted to make a simple Tic Tac Toe game for my first project by myself (not school related, just for fun), but I have been struggling to fix some errors for the past few days.

First, I have been wondering if there is a way for me to return a variable to my 'Checkerboard' function so I don't have to call it after every move. Right now I have to call the 'Checkerboard' after every move, but I'm wondering if there is a way to return the placement of the X or O right to the original function so a new board does not pop up after every move.

Next, when I am using the 'CheckMove' functions my two "if" statements will not run one after the other (i,e. if I type a number that has already been used and then a number outside of the scope 0-10, my program does not run correctly). My program runs fine if I only do one of these things, but as soon as I do them back to back it fails to work properly.

Finally, I cannot figure out why my code will not stop running when a winner is declared (see 'CheckWinner function).

On a side note, as this is my first code any other suggestions on how to improve it would be highly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void Checkerboard(char SpaceNumber[]);
void CheckMoveX(int Player[], int Choice, char SpaceNumber[]);
void CheckMoveO(int Player[], int Choice, char SpaceNumber[]);
int CheckWinner(char SpaceNumber[], int CheckWin);

void main()
{
    char SpaceNumber[9] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    int Player[2] = {1, 2}, Choice, CheckWin=0;

    cout << "          Tic Tac Toe\n\n";
    cout << "Player 1: 'X' --- Player 2: 'O'\n\n";
    Checkerboard(SpaceNumber);

    do {
        cout << "\nPlayer " << Player[0] << " pick a number to place your mark...";
        cin >> Choice;
        CheckMoveX(Player, Choice, SpaceNumber);    

        CheckWinner(SpaceNumber, CheckWin);

        cout << "\nPlayer " << Player[1] << " pick a number to place your mark..."; //The rest of the main function is a duplicate of the first half, but it is for player 2.
        cin >> Choice;
        CheckMoveO(Player, Choice, SpaceNumber);

        CheckWinner(SpaceNumber, CheckWin);
        }while (CheckWinner != 0); //Program isn't ending when winner occurs.
    _getch();
}

void Checkerboard(char SpaceNumber[])
{
    cout << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[0] << setw(3) << "|" << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[1] << setw(3) << "|" << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[2] << endl;
    cout << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << endl;

    cout << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[3] << setw(3) << "|" << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[4] << setw(3) << "|" << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[5] << endl;
    cout << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << setw(2) << "-" << endl;

    cout << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[6] << setw(3) << "|" << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[7] << setw(3) << "|" << setw(3) << SpaceNumber[8] << endl;
}
void CheckMoveX(int Player[], int Choice, char SpaceNumber[]) //I cannot seem to have the first/second "if" statements run back to back.
{
    do {
        if (Choice > 0 && Choice < 10)
        {
            if (SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] == 'X' || SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] == 'O') //This loop ensures that the same square cannot be picked twice.
            {
                do {
                    cout << "This number has already been chosen. Please pick a different number...";
                    cin >> Choice;
                } while (SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] == 'X' || SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] == 'O');
            }
            SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] = 'X';
            Checkerboard(SpaceNumber);
        }

        if (Choice < 1 || Choice > 9)//Forces the user to pick a number on the board.
        {
            do {
                    cout << "Invalid choice. Please pick another number...";
                    cin >> Choice;
                } while (Choice < 1 || Choice > 9);

                SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] = 'X';
                Checkerboard(SpaceNumber);
        }
    } while (SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] != 'X');
}
void CheckMoveO(int Player[], int Choice, char SpaceNumber[]) //Duplicate of CheckMoveO
{
    if (Choice > 0 && Choice < 10)
    {
        if (SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] == 'X' || SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] == 'O')
        {
            do {
                cout << "This number has already been chosen. Please pick a different number...";
                cin >> Choice;
            } while (SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] == 'X' || SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] == 'O');
        }
        SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] = 'O';
        Checkerboard(SpaceNumber);
    }

    if (Choice < 1 || Choice > 9)
    {
        do {
                cout << "Invalid choice. Please pick another number...";
                cin >> Choice;
            } while (Choice < 1 || Choice > 9);

            SpaceNumber[Choice - 1] = 'O';
            Checkerboard(SpaceNumber);
    }
}
int CheckWinner(char SpaceNumber[], int CheckWin)
{
    if (SpaceNumber[0] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[3] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[6] == 'X') //Not sure how to do this without if/else statements.
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[1] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[4] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[7] == 'X')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!";
        return CheckWin;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[2] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[5] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[7] == 'X')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[0] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[1] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[2] == 'X')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[3] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[4] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[5] == 'X')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[6] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[7] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[8] == 'X')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[0] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[4] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[8] == 'X')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[2] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[4] == 'X' && SpaceNumber[6] == 'X')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins";
        return 0;
    }

    //End Player 1 Win. Begin Player 2 Win (Duplicate Code).

    else if (SpaceNumber[0] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[3] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[6] == 'O') //Not sure how to do this without if/else statements.
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[1] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[4] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[7] == 'O')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[2] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[5] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[7] == 'O')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[0] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[1] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[2] == 'O')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[3] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[4] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[5] == 'O')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[6] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[7] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[8] == 'O')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[0] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[4] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[8] == 'O')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins";
        return 0;
    }
    else if (SpaceNumber[2] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[4] == 'O' && SpaceNumber[6] == 'O')
    {
        CheckWin = 0;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins";
        return 0;
    }

    //End player 2 win; begin cout for tie game.

    else
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You're not saving the value of `CheckWinner` to `CheckWin`

Replace `CheckWinner(SpaceNumber, CheckWin);` with `CheckWin = CheckWinner(SpaceNumber, CheckWin);`

2) You need to check if `(CheckWin != 0)` instead of `(CheckWinner != 0)`

3) You're not checking if the game ended before taking the input for the next move.

**Replace your** `do.. while` **block in your** `main` **function with this**

```
do {
    CheckWin = CheckWinner(SpaceNumber, CheckWin);
    if (CheckWin!=0)
    {
    cout << "\nPlayer " << Player[0] << " pick a number to place your mark...";
    cin >> Choice;
    CheckMoveX(Player, Choice, SpaceNumber);
    }

    CheckWin = CheckWinner(SpaceNumber, CheckWin);
    if (CheckWin != 0 )
    {
    cout << "\nPlayer " << Player[1] << " pick a number to place your mark...";
    cin >> Choice;
    CheckMoveO(Player, Choice, SpaceNumber);
    }

}while (CheckWin != 0);
```

That should solve your problem. Let me know if you have some other issue with the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked out perfect and helped me understand what I was doing wrong. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling CheckWinner in your while condition, you are comparing the address of CheckWinner which will never be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of duplicate code.  Rather than two `CheckMove` functions, just have one and pass in an 'X' or 'O' to compare with.  You can do the same thing with `CheckWinner` (which has an incorrect subscript in the 3rd comparison).

For your second question, the problem in `CheckMove` is that in the `do`/`while` loop you get the input value but don't validate it.

There are two reasons why your program doesn't stop when you have a winner:  The first is that after 'X' moves you check for a winner but don't check the result of that before having 'O' move.  The second is that your comparison, `CheckWinner != 0` is checking the address of a function for zero (which will never happen), rather than your `CheckWin` variable.  This would work better if CheckWinner returned the winner rather than setting a global variable.

I'm not sure what you're asking with your first question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not still unsure about the second question though. By validate the input value do you mean I should I return the value and then check to see if it is correct?

Comment: @Planets14 You need to validate that the new input value is still valid.  You do that at the start of the function (`if (Choice > 0 && Choice < 10)` but if that square is already used you ask for a new one and don't check to see if it is in that range.